# How to rerun kotlin project when I update a file in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Ideally, in Intellij IDEA I'd like to be able to debug a java project, then have the IDE restart debugging the project when I edit a file. If that's not possible, a keyboard shortcut would help (something equivalent to the restart button in the debugger panel). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ctrl+f5` to kill the current instance of your application, and rerun it.